# Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a array (from a global constants file) which I am trying to use in an API call to make another dictionary array. The initial array is:

```
let callCountries = ["AU" : "Australia", "NZ" : "New Zealand", "UK" : "United Kingdom", "ZA" : "South Africa", "US" : "United States"]
```

I then just want to grab the country shortcode and loop through it to build a new array as per below...

```
func getCallCentreNumbers(){

    var countrykeys = Array(callCountries.keys)

    API.getJudeContactNumbers({response in

            self.judeCallCentreNumberDict =  [
                countrykeys : (response.value(forKey: countrykeys) as! String),
        ]

    })

}
```

The initial line of code without the array values being inserted was:

```
self.judeCallCentreNumberDict =  [
                "ZM" : (response.value(forKey: "ZM") as! String),
        ]
```

I want to replace the "ZM"s with the countrykeys variable but cannot work this one out. (Sorry I am still quite a newbie). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what is `"ZM"` because I can't see any key with that name

Comment: `value(forKey` expects a single string, `countrykeys` is an array of string. The types don't match. That's what the error message says. And your *initial array* is actually a dictionary. There is no need to convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a loop through out the response

First try to clear `judeCallCentreNumberDict` before making the request

```
judeCallCentreNumberDict = [:]
```

Then when you have the response make an array of the keys and loop through it

(inside `API.getJudeContactNumbers({response in`)

```
let countrykeys = callCountries.map { $0.key }

countrykeys.forEach {
    guard let value = response.value(forKey: $0) as? String else { return }
    judeCallCentreNumberDict[$0] = value
}
```

Note:

- `$0` means the current item in the loop (in this case it will be one of the keys)
- I'm guessing that `judeCallCentreNumberDict` is of type `[String:String]` so we can add to it only values of type `String` not `String?` and that is what the `guard` is for

Comment: Consider two logical things: You got **all** keys so it's guaranteed that there is always a value for the key and the dictionary is clearly `[String:String]` (the `guard` will never fail) and you are converting a dictionary to a dictionary, after the loop `judeCallCentreNumberDict == response`

Comment: Thanks - this worked a treat. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to look at each number in the response and build a dictionary of the numbers for each country code. You were close to this implementation, but you need to iterate over the keys in `countrykeys`, looking at the value for each key and assigning that value to the corresponding country code in `judeCallCentreNumberDict`.

```
func getCallCentreNumbers() {
    var countrykeys = Array(callCountries.keys)

    API.getJudeContactNumbers { response in
        for countryKey in countryKeys {
            let number = (response.value(forKey: countrykeys) as! String)
            self.judeCallCentreNumberDict[countryKey] = number
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will solve the compiler problem, but it seems like this code is unnecessary for what you want to do (at least in the context given). If all you want to do is make that API call and get a dictionary of contact numbers, it seems like that API is handling that sufficiently for you. It seems like the API is returning a dictionary of phone numbers for you already. So the code could be cut down to something like the code below. (Unless the response is returning JSON, in which case these implementations will fail)

```
func getCallCentreNumbers() {   
    API.getJudeContactNumbers { response in
        self.judeCallCentreNumberDict = response
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The code is returning JSON but your answer was really helpful.